# Convert SHA1 password to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity PasswordHasher

Tags: c#, sha1, password-encryption

I have a new application which uses Microsoft.AspNet.Identity PasswordHasher. I am trying to import all the login information from the old system which uses SHA1 passwords to the new system.

I know SHA1 is a one-way hash and it cannot be decrypted. Is there any way possible way to do this?. Otherwise what are my best options?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need both hashes in your new system. If the old hash is non-null, then, when a person tries to log in, verify against the old hash... if all is good, create a new hash with the verified password and delete the old hash.

Comment: Thank you spender.